# Php Write Text on the Image, SAVE OPTION

Tags: php

Well, this is what I have right now.

```
$bg = imagecreatefrompng('bg.png');

$font = "font.ttf";

$white = imagecolorallocate($bg, 255, 255, 255);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagettftext($bg, 25, 0, 5, 83, $white, $font, date('d.m.Y'));
imagettftext($bg, 30, 0, 5, 145, $white, $font, date('H:i'));

imagepng($bg);
imagedestroy($bg);
```

I would like to know how can I actually save created image.
I was trying to do something like that:

```
imagepng($bg,"/users/user/");
```

To save is but it doesn't work at all.
So can anybody tell me how to save image?

Thank you.

Comment: you need too add a file name

Comment: So how should It look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
imagepng($bg, "/users/user/bg.png");
imagedestroy($bg);
```